# Entity Framework Pre Generated View on custom queries

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a following Data Structure EntityObject (Unit, Product, ...) 1 : 1 Translation 1:n Translation Items.

To fill ComboBoxes and listViews i only need to query the Translations this way:

```
    public CollectionViewSource GetShowColumns()
    {
        CollectionViewSource result = new CollectionViewSource();
        List<UnitDTO> units = new List<UnitDTO>();
        var qry = from x in _context.Units
                  select new
                  {
                      x.Name,
                      x.Name.Translations,
                      x.Id
                  };

        foreach (var temp in qry)
        {
            units.Add(new UnitDTO() { Id = temp.Id, Name = temp.Name });
        }
        result.Source = units;
        return result;
    }
```

My DTO Object contains an Id and Translation Property.

I already used [EF Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) To Prgenerate views. But i still experience a huge differnece between warm and cold queries.

What shall i do ?

Comment: What is the difference you experience, performance related, data structure related? What is the question?

Comment: The query takes cold somewhat between 3 and 5 secs and warm less than 0.5 secs

Comment: A thing that may help here is compiled queries. If you are on .NET Framework 4.5 you will get this feature by default as the queries are auto-compiled. The first time query is run it takes a bit more time. You also should take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx